# Can I use the same entity in two different relationship with two different tables?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, asp.net-core-6.0, ef-core-6.0

Imagine this class diagram

```
public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public List<City> AuthorizedCities { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public List<City> AuthorizedCities { get; set; }
}
```

By default, Entity Framework will map this to 3 tables

Employee -->> City <<-- Customer
Where the City table has two foreign keys (EmployeeId, CustomerId) assuming that EF core will ensure that only either is filled.

Is there a way, to make the relationship between each Employee/Customer and the City at two different tables?

Say EmployeeCities and CustomerCities, but without duplicating the City class?

I'm looking for an answer using modelBuilder as opposed to attributes over the class properties.

For example `modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>.Whatever`

Comment: But without a `City` table data would have to be duplicated. Imagine an `Employee` and a `Customer` both authorize the same city (say Istanbul). Which of the two tables will hold the "true" data about Istanbul? How do you plan to maintain the city data? How do you wanna keep it in sync?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride
I should be more clear on this, the example is not very identical to my case, so you can assume safely that it is Ok to have duplicate data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup models in such way that they represent many-to-many relationship. For example add `Employees` and `Customers` collections to `City` entity:

```
public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public List<Customers> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

And EF Core should automatically setup the underlying tables (including the join ones).

Documentation for [many-to-many relationships in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many).

**UPD**

EF has convention - one entity type - one table, so you need to create 2 different entity types (you can inherit them both from the base `City`):

```cs
public abstract class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeCity : City {}

public class Employee
{
    public List<EmployeeCity> AuthorizedCities { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerCity : City {}

public class Customer
{
    public List<CustomerCity> AuthorizedCities { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: But this will create two junction tables `EmployeeCities` and `CustomerCities` along with the already existing 3 tables `Employee`, `Customer`, and `City`. What I'm looking for is to replace the `City` with two tables `EmployeeCities` and `CustomerCities` tables

Comment: @Nour see the update. Though I would argue that having junction tables makes more sense.

Comment: thanks, that would work. I know it doesn't make sense in this example because City is an identified entity, that behaves the same if it is an employee or a customer. but my case is slightly different and I didn't want to post the exact example to avoid leaking any private code.